# How do I set the Ledger Nano S to display the recipient's full address?

Tags: transactions, wallets, security, signature, ledger-nano-s

Presently the Ledger Nano S is showing only the first few first and last digits, with the middle truncated. Why does it truncate the middle of the address? How do we display the entire address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have [the latest firmware](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165409-How-can-I-update-my-Nano-S-), you must [use the Ledger Manager to update the Ethereum app](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005173289) to the latest version.